# How do I make my character sit?

Tags: armature

I have imported my character from makeHuman and wanted to animate it from the Standing position to the Sitting Position (Lap) Can anyone give me a detailed description? :( I've been trying but the problem is that when the animation plays, the feet moves up when I wanted it to take the feet as pivot and make the body kneel down to sitting. Please help :(

[image: Standing]

[image: Sitting]

As you can see, the feet does not remain on floor.. Please help! :( I would be more than grateful.. :)

Comment: animate the root bone to move down while he is bending his legs